# XAML AdMediator windows 10 configuration - nothing I do shows the ad.

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10

I'm having a hard time getting my ad to show.

Here is my ad element:

```
<Universal:AdMediatorControl x:Name="AdMediator_2CB784" Height="80" Id="AdMediator-Id-30C8B005-60BC-4616-A7E5-06946A425C5D" Margin="0"  Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

In visual studios I added the connected service and I configured the Ad Mediation during the first submission (It passed certification but I haven't published it.)

This is what autopopulated when I added the connected service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AdMediatorConfiguration xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <BaseConfiguration>  
    <AdAdapters>
      <AdAdapterInfo>
        <Metadata>
          <Property>
            <Key>WApplicationId</Key>
            <Value>fc24e866-0e16-40be-8c10-6908c9b6a4b7</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Key>MApplicationId</Key>
            <Value>fc24e866-0e16-40be-8c10-6908c9b6a4b7</Value>
          </Property>
        </Metadata>
        <Name>MicrosoftAdvertising</Name>
        <Weight>100</Weight>
      </AdAdapterInfo>
    </AdAdapters>
    <AdAdapters>
      <AdAdapterInfo>
        <Metadata>
          <Property>
            <Key>WApplicationId</Key>
            <Value>f005d95d-4adf-4b55-8020-3b56d74f3253</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Key>WAdUnitId</Key>
            <Value>242247</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Key>WWidth</Key>
            <Value>300</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Key>WHeight</Key>
            <Value>250</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Key>MApplicationId</Key>
            <Value>22c93881-85e4-487e-bd1a-b9175857e320</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Key>MAdUnitId</Key>
            <Value>242249</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Key>MWidth</Key>
            <Value>480</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Key>MHeight</Key>
            <Value>80</Value>
          </Property>
        </Metadata>
        <Name>MicrosoftAdvertising</Name>
        <Rank>1</Rank>
        <Weight>100</Weight>
      </AdAdapterInfo>
    </AdAdapters>
    <AdControlConfigurations>
      <AdControlConfiguration>
        <AdAdapters>
          <AdAdapterInfo>
            <Metadata>
              <Property>
                <Key>WAdUnitId</Key>
                <Value>10043121</Value>
              </Property>
              <Property>
                <Key>MAdUnitId</Key>
                <Value>10865270</Value>
              </Property>
            </Metadata>
            <Name>MicrosoftAdvertising</Name>
          </AdAdapterInfo>
        </AdAdapters>
        <Id>AdMediator-Id-30C8B005-60BC-4616-A7E5-06946A425C5D</Id>
        <Name>AdMediator_2CB784</Name>
      </AdControlConfiguration>
    </AdControlConfigurations>
  </BaseConfiguration>
  <FileVersion>1.0.1</FileVersion>
  <RefreshRate>30</RefreshRate>
  <SchemaVersion>1.0.3</SchemaVersion>
  <UpdatedDateTime>2015-09-06T15:06:23.7901527Z</UpdatedDateTime>
  <UseRoundRobin>true</UseRoundRobin>
</AdMediatorConfiguration>
```

Per the developer dashboard, fc24e866-0e16-40be-8c10-6908c9b6a4b7 is my application ID.  I'm not sure if there should be two  or not, but I tried removing those nodes, changing the ID value to my application ID, but nothing happens.

In my app, there just a blank space where my ad unit is.  Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here. My supposition is that my country is not on the list of countries where ads are supported - maybe you have the same situation? By the way can you tell me the difference between WAdUnitId and MAdUnitId?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me, but I am still not certain it is the best control.

Here's the link I followed:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt219682.aspx